# Run an arbitrary command when a service fails

Tags: systemd

I want to run some script when a service fails. The closest thing I see to this is the `FailureAction=` option (under `[Service]` section), but it only offers reboot commands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an `OnFailure=` directive in section `[Unit]`, documented in [systemd.unit(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#OnFailure=). It is defined as follows:

> A space-separated list of one or more units that are activated when this unit enters the "failed" state.

*(Also there is an `OnFailureJobMode=` directive in the same section which allows to set job mode for activating OnFailure= units.)*

Comment: Looks like those options start other units instead just scripts.

Comment: @Tshepang: Of course. In systemd, a unit is, well, a basic *unit* of doing anything. Write a simple unit for your script, put it under `/etc/systemd/system` and place its name in the `OnFailure=` directive.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `ExecStopPost` to run a command directly instead of starting a unit.

I wasn't happy with the `OnFailure` setting so I kept looking and found `ExecStopPost`.

The the following real example, if the main task fails then systemd will run a `git` command.

```
[Unit]
Description=SRI Dispenser Server
ConditionPathExists=|/usr/bin/
After=sri-boot-dsp.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/sri/configurations/transmitter

User=root

# This is task to run when this service starts
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -m sri.DispenserServer

# If any of the ExecStart tasks fail, then ExecStopPost will run
ExecStopPost=/bin/git checkout -- .

Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGKILL


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

> ExecStopPost= Additional commands that are executed after the service
>   is stopped. This includes cases where the commands configured in
>   ExecStop= were used, where the service does not have any ExecStop=
>   defined, or where the service exited unexpectedly. This argument takes
>   multiple command lines, following the same scheme as described for
>   ExecStart=. Use of these settings is optional. Specifier and
>   environment variable substitution is supported. Note that – unlike
>   ExecStop= – commands specified with this setting are invoked when a
>   service failed to start up correctly and is shut down again.
>
> It is recommended to use this setting for clean-up operations that
>   shall be executed even when the service failed to start up correctly.
>   Commands configured with this setting need to be able to operate even
>   if the service failed starting up half-way and left incompletely
>   initialized data around. As the service's processes have been
>   terminated already when the commands specified with this setting are
>   executed they should not attempt to communicate with them.
>
> Note that all commands that are configured with this setting are
>   invoked with the result code of the service, as well as the main
>   process' exit code and status, set in the $SERVICE_RESULT, $EXIT_CODE
>   and $EXIT_STATUS environment variables, see systemd.exec(5) for
>   details.