# SystemD, disable service when fails, how?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to create a service (namely a Minecraft Server) in SystemD, and on a machine which is set up to reboot daily.

In case when the server crashes, I would like to have the service be disabled by itself, such that it won't try to spin up again, even across the scheduled reboots, to prevent it from crashing again and have the data corrupted, and to let me investigate the situation.

Is it possible to be achieved in SystemD? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your post to include the `systemd` code/service.

Comment: Create another unit wich starts on failure and disable your service from it https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197641/153329

Comment: Why would the server crash? Purely hypothetical, or real?

Comment: @U.Windl It's currently only hypothetical. However, since I'm opening the Minecraft server to the internet for my friends, I would like to be better prepared for such scenario so as to prevent data corruption from the server restarting.

Comment: @gapsf Thank you for your idea! I've read through the [`systemd.exec(5)` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#%24SERVICE_RESULT) again, which the `$SERVICE_RESULT` seems could be utilized in my case with `ExecStopPost=`. I'll post an answer when I come up with a solution.

Comment: I wonder: What is wrong with not using `systemd` at all, and just start the service manually once? Then if the service fails, it won't be restarted, and if the server reboots, it would not be restarted. However if the server restarts unexpectedly, you would have to star the service manually again.